# Not able to start rails server in 5.0.0.1 rails but works fine with 4.2.0.beta1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am still learning ROR and I have spent a lot of time trying to figure it out.

I have tried to install all sorts of gems from different stackoverflow answers. Is there anyone that can help me with this? Thank You

How can I get to work with the latest version (5.0.0.1) it says:

```
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 4.2.2 application starting in development on http://localhost:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Exiting
/home/ubuntu/workspace/hellp_app/config/environments/development.rb:53:in `block in <top (required)>': uninitialized constant ActiveSupport::EventedFileUpdateChecker (NameError)
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/railtie.rb:210:in `instance_eval'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/railtie.rb:210:in `configure'
    from /home/ubuntu/workspace/hellp_app/config/environments/development.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:598:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:597:in `each'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:597:in `block in <class:Engine>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:228:in `block in tsort_each'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:350:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:422:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:431:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:421:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `each'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `tsort_each_child'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:415:in `call'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:415:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:349:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:347:in `call'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:226:in `tsort_each'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/application.rb:352:in `initialize!'
    from /home/ubuntu/workspace/hellp_app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/ubuntu/workspace/hellp_app/config.ru:3:in `require_relative'
    from /home/ubuntu/workspace/hellp_app/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
    from /home/ubuntu/workspace/hellp_app/config.ru:in `new'
    from /home/ubuntu/workspace/hellp_app/config.ru:in `<main>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:299:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:208:in `app'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:61:in `app'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:336:in `wrapped_app'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:139:in `log_to_stdout'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:78:in `start'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:80:in `block in server'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/ubuntu/workspace/hellp_app/bin/rails:9:in `require'
    from /home/ubuntu/workspace/hellp_app/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:27:in `load'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:27:in `call'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/client.rb:26:in `run'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.1.3/bin/spring:48:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `load'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/ubuntu/workspace/hellp_app/bin/spring:13:in `require'
    from /home/ubuntu/workspace/hellp_app/bin/spring:13:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:3:in `load'
    from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Have you read the [upgrade guide](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html)?

Comment: @Dragon. Can you post your Gemfile?

Comment: Thanks for answering. I have already updated and I guess tha'ts why it wouldn't work but is there a way to make it work in the latest version?

Comment: [this one](https://github.com/mhartl/rails_tutorial_3rd_edition_gemfiles/blob/master/hello_app/Gemfile)

Comment: For rails 5 the default server is puma. Take out the webrick gem and add puma gem, then go configure puma.rb in initializers. If you create a new rails project the puma.rb is configured automatically, so you can just CC that from there. Btw. if you have no particular reason to choose something else then you should always stick with puma webserver and postgres db both in development and production.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the gemfile you posted, the Rails version is incorrect:

```
gem 'rails',        '4.2.2'
```

Since you are attempting to start version 5.0.0.1, you should update it accordingly in your gemfile, then run:

```
bundle install
```

to install dependendies for the newest version.